# Regular Expression Credit Cards

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression that will mask a 16 digit credit card number but not mask a UPS Tracking number.  UPS Tracking numbers start with "1Z".

I've tried ^(?!1Z).+[0-9]{16}

Thanks,
Andrew

Comment: Did you even try anything?

Comment: ^(?!1Z).+[0-9]{16} but it is throwing an error.

Comment: Please include the error, and code to reproduce this.

Comment: I am doing this in the Oracle Service Cloud so it does not show me the exact error, but when I tested using the following tracking number it said there was an error: 1Z6E49030393942933

Answer (score 2):

As per [this tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/creditcard.html) :

```
^(?:4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?          # Visa
 |  5[1-5][0-9]{14}                  # MasterCard
 |  3[47][0-9]{13}                   # American Express
 |  3(?:0[0-5]|[68][0-9])[0-9]{11}   # Diners Club
 |  6(?:011|5[0-9]{2})[0-9]{12}      # Discover
 |  (?:2131|1800|35\d{3})\d{11}      # JCB
)$
```

This will ensure your credit card number is valid. However, If all you want is check that your 16 digit number is not a UPS tracking number, this sould do :

```
\d{16}
```